# pandas.DataFrame.append is adding new columns to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

First, I created a csv file from data0 as shown:

```
data0 = ["car", 0.82, 0.0026, 0.914, 0.59]
test_df = pd.DataFrame([data0])
test_df.to_csv("testfile1.csv")
```

Output of that "testfile1.csv" appears like this:

```
     0     1       2      3     4
0   car  0.82  0.0026  0.914  0.59
```

I want to append new data (data1 = ["bus", 0.9, 0.123, 12.907, 42], data2 = ["van", 0.23, 0.41, .031, 0.894, 6.16, 4.104]) to old csv file so that it appears in new row but exactly under previous rows as shown below:

```
     0     1       2       3       4     5      6
0  car  0.82  0.0026   0.914   0.590   NaN    NaN
1  bus  0.90  0.1230  12.907  42.000   NaN    NaN
2  van  0.23  0.4100   0.031   0.894  6.16  4.104
```

I tried program and other similar methods using .append() or .to_csv() with mode="a":

```
test_df = pd.read_csv("testfile1.csv", index_col=0)
test_df = test_df.append([data1], ignore_index=True)
test_df = test_df.append([data2], ignore_index=True)
test_df.to_csv("testfile1.csv")
```

However, every time new data is appended in new columns and not under previous columns:

```
     0     1      2       3       4  ...    0     1       2      3     4
0  NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  ...  car  0.82  0.0026  0.914  0.59
1  bus  0.90  0.123  12.907  42.000  ...  NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
2  van  0.23  0.410   0.031   0.894  ...  NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN   NaN
```

My project is to read existing CSV file, appending and saving back to same file. I even tried type casting to pandas.Series

Comment: Do you intend to add a new row that has a different shape from the original dataframe?

Comment: I tried the code you posted and got the output you're looking for. Perhaps you left something out? Did you define `data1` and `data2` as lists as you indicated in plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to turn the list into pandas series first:

```py
data1 = ['bus', 0.90,   0.1230, 12.907, 42.000]
row1 = pd.Series(data1)

data2 = ["van", 0.23, 0.41, .031, 0.894, 6.16, 4.104]
row2 = pd.Series(data2)
```

Then append it:

```py
test_df = test_df.append(row1, ignore_index=True)
test_df = test_df.append(row2, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```py
    0   1       2       3       4       5       6
0   car 0.82    0.0026  0.914   0.590   NaN     NaN
1   bus 0.90    0.1230  12.907  42.000  NaN     NaN
2   van 0.23    0.4100  0.031   0.894   6.16    4.104
```